# Ignoring parameters names in serialization and deserialization with JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have this two classes as an example:

```
public class Joints_
{   
    public Dictionary<string, int> joints_;
    public Joints_()
    {
        joints_ = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }
    public Joints_(bool inizializza)
    {
        joints_ = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                joints_["x"] = 678;
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                joints_["y"] = 2646;
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                joints_["z"] = 1234;
            }
        }
    }
    public void SaveWithJson(string fileName, ref Joints_ c)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c, Formatting.Indented));
    }
}

public class Persona_
{
    public Dictionary<string, Joints_> persona_;
    public Persona_()
    {
        persona_ = new Dictionary<string, Joints_>();
    }
    public Persona_(bool inizializza)
    {
        persona_ = new Dictionary<string, Joints_>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++)
        {
            persona_["joint_" + i] = new Joints_(true);
        }
    }
    public void SaveWithJson(string fileName, ref Persona_ c)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c, Formatting.Indented));
    }
}
```

When I serialize an object of Persona_ type, i get this:

```
{
"persona_": {
  "joint_1": {
    "joints_": {
      "x": 678,
      "y": 2646,
      "z": 1234
    }
   },
etc etc....
```

The problem is that I want this (without the name of the parameter, just with the value):

```
    {
  "persona_": {
    "joint_1": {
        "x": 678,
        "y": 2646,
        "z": 1234
    },
etc etc....
```

How can I do it? Before you ask, I didn't find solution for this SPECIFIC problem.

Also, I have the opposite problem with deserialization: I have a file that doesn't have the name of the parameter.

For example, it has just "joint_15" instead of "joint_15: {(new line) joint: etc etc..."

Is there maybe a keyword to put before the parameter to solve this?
Something like [JsonIgnore]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override serialization behavior using custom `JsonConverter`. Mark your `Joints_` class with attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JointsConverter))]
public class Joints_
```

Where `JointsConverter` is your custom converter (code with my comments):

```
public class JointsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => true; // converter can deserialize too

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var joints = value as Joints_;
        var jObject = JObject.FromObject(joints.joints_); // we're converting to json just joints_ instead of whole object

        jObject.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // we're initializing joints_ dictionary from saved values
        var joints = new Joints_
        {
            joints_ = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, int>>(reader)
        };

        return joints;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Joints_);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just add to also type "using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;"
<3

Comment: In `WriteJson` you can just do `serializer.Serialize(writer, joints.joints_);`, skipping the intermediate `jObject` representation.